# Crop a imageView using a customView

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm making an application which can crop a picture of a person. I have also attached the image to show exactly what I'm making. It is just like WhatsApp application. The blue square is actually a customView extended from View class. I'm overriding onDraw() function which uses canvas to draw the square. How can I capture image defined by area of blue square?[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the exact coordinates of your blue area and then create a bitmap from the original one using the coordinates you just calculated!

```
Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap,x,y,width,height);
```

Comment: Yeah. I will monitor the coordinates of blue area when I move and then use them to create a new Image. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm able to implement this, but one question arises that is it the correct way to implement it or there are better ways. Is getting the exact coordinates a good idea? Thanks

Comment: You just need to take care of the scalings i think. Except for that this is the only way i know! If someone knows something more maybe they can help you out!